# BizTalk is picking up the machine.config file instead of the External config file in BizTalk Configuration File Configuration file

Tags: .net, config, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I installed a new solution and I have this issue with BizTalk, it's picking up the machine.config file values (appseting) instead of the external config file in BizTalk Configuration File.

Do you have any idea? It has been a week searching for a solution and I can't find the issue. FYI : I don't have this issue in the integration environment (dbs are hosted locally, stand-alone), for now I have this issue in the UAT environment (the DB servers are hosted in an external server).

Another thing, this is a new installed platform 2020, I suspect that something is missing but i can't confirm , or is it only a access right issue?

Comment: For external config file, do you mean BTSNTSvc64.exe.config and BTSNTSvc.exe.config ?